# How to get all one to many relationship in Core data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

```
NSArray * relationships = [entity.relationshipsByName allKeys];
```

Will return ALL relationships.

What about if I only want relationships that's one to Many? That is relationship that support selector count.

How would I do so?

Comment: Actually it'll only pull out an array of relationship names

Comment: Actually yes. Some technicality..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you loop through the `NSDictionary` returned by `entity.relationshipsByName`, each value is an `NSRelationshipDescription` instance which has the property `isToMany`. You could pull out only the relationships where that property is true?